# .htaccess RewriteRule doesn't work :/

Tags: .htaccess

I thinks it's a small mistake but I can't solve it even after loonking for lots of other posts about it ...
the last RewriteRule doesn't work (in http://localhost/Hegalaldia) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Hegalaldia/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Hegalaldia/index.php [L]

# This doesn't work :
  RewriteRule ^Centres-de-soins-pour-animaux-sauvages-en-France.html$ /wp-content/themes/c7hegalaldia/includes/map_centres_soin/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

Unless a file by that name exists, that rule won't be reached, as the previous rule triggers, and immediately rewrites the request to index.php.

You need to move that rule up before the previous rule and its two conds (or even further up).

Comment: I changed index.php with map.php :        RewriteRule ^Centres-de-soins-pour-animaux-sauvages-en-France.html$ /wp-content/themes/c7hegalaldia/includes/map_centres_soin/map.php but it still doesn't work. Any other advice ? Thanks !